# How to develop facebook apps for another business?

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I am developing bots with Microsoft Bot Framework. I have a Facebook Business account and Facebook Developer account, and a page for my own business which my bot is running in the messenger of the page.

I want to develop and sell bots which operate in my customers Facebook pages. What is the right/legal/Facebook way to do it? Should i request their business and developer accounts and develop my bot there or is there something like business assosication what i can develop my app on my own and hand over to their accounts and page/pages?

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends also builds and sells bots to various businesses online. He offers his service on Fivver: https://www.fiverr.com/gigs/messenger-bot a freelance platform. As far as I've learned from him there's nothing illegal by setting up Facebook bots for other pages.

Comment: I can get their business account and developer account user names and passwords and i can make all the settings, but i thought this will be illegal because this is their account. How is your friend does this ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question really depends on your scenario.  If you are using Azure Bot Service and each customer will have their own instance of the bot running on a different URL, then you will need to register (or have your customers register) separate apps in Facebook and then configure these individually for each bot.  You can develop your bot using your own Facebook app to test and then publish the bot when ready and configure the bot to be connected to their Facebook page.

You may also be able to create new pages in Facebook and set everything up and then add your customer as an administrator / transfer the page to them, however, this would be a question for Facebook as I am not an expert in their processes and capabilities.

If you are planning to create a single bot that works for many customers (i.e. multi tenant scenario), then you could consider using the Facebook Adapter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-a-facebook-app-page-and-gather-credentials), by doing this you can configure multiple Facebook pages to hit the same bot and you would then need to add some code to your bot to determine which Facebook page / customer the request is coming from. This would be custom code for your scenario though.

Gary

Comment: My customers will have different bots, so different facebook apps needs to be created. How will i connect my facebook app to a page that belongs to my customer? Will they invite my developer account as a page owner or something?